# Is it possible to combine both cross validation time serie and stratified

Tags: machine-learning, python, cross-validation

We suppose that I have the following dataset, where:

The data describe the behaviors of each employ during the realization of his mission from the first day he starts working on the society. Each employee must complete a mission, and he could succeed in a task, or he could get fail.

Generally, in our data we have this case: the firsts tasks are usually failed because the employee still unfamiliar with the new mission and the latest tasks realized by an employee are usually succeeded.

I would like to apply cross-validation for splitting my data by taking into consideration that the latest task of each mission is mostly successful (something looks like the use of time series!), and I need also to use the notion of cross-validation stratified k-fold for training and testing my model according to each employee. I am still a beginner in machine learning and I would like to know if there is a similar method for splitting data according to these conditions or if it is possible to combine both cross-validation method (CV time series and stratified) for splitting my data.

````
ID_Employ       Mission_Id       Task        Succeed       
1                  M_1            T1            0
1                  M_1            T2            0
1                  M_1            T3            1 
1                  M_1            T4            0
1                  M_1            T5            0
1                  M_1            T6            1
1                  M_1            T7            1
1                  M_1            T8            1

1                  M_2            T1            0
1                  M_2            T2            1
1                  M_2            T3            0 
1                  M_2            T4            1
1                  M_2            T5            1
1                  M_2            T6            1

1                  M_3            T1            0
1                  M_3            T2            0
......
2                  M_1            T1            0
2                  M_1            T2            0
2                  M_1            T3            1 
2                  M_1            T4            0
2                  M_1            T5            1
2                  M_1            T6            1

2                  M_2            T1            0
2                  M_2            T2            0
2                  M_2            T3            0 
2                  M_2            T4            1
2                  M_2            T5            1
2                  M_2            T6            0
2                  M_2            T7            1
2                  M_2            T8            1
```
````